# When I tried python -m pip install --upgrade pip , in termux this happened :

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, termux

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import PackageFinder
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .html5parser import HTMLParser, parse, parseFragment
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import _tokenizer
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_tokenizer.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ._trie import Trie
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_trie/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .py import Trie as PyTrie
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_trie/py.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._base import Trie as ABCTrie
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_trie/_base.py", line 3, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you check out [this article on Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and edit your post? That way it'll be easier for us to see!

Comment: It should be `from collections.abc import Mapping`, but not sure why that mistake has been made...

Comment: The `collections` module in Python 2.x had a `Mapping` class. Looks like some sort of version skew here.